# Edit and update contact's data in android

Tags: android

i made an application that have read/write contacts permissions. i'm trying to make an updating function that gets new display name, an email address and phone number to add by using this:

```
public void updateContact(Context ctx, String name, String number, String email,String ContactId) {
    try {
        name = name.trim();
        email = email.trim();
        number = number.trim();

        ContentResolver contentResolver  = ctx.getContentResolver();

        String where = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";

        String[] emailParams = new String[]{ContactId, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
        String[] nameParams = new String[]{ContactId, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
        String[] numberParams = new String[]{ContactId, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};

        ArrayList<android.content.ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<android.content.ContentProviderOperation>();

        if(!email.equals(""))
        {
            ops.add(android.content.ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(android.provider.ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withSelection(where,emailParams)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, email)
                    .build());
        }

        if(!name.equals(""))
        {
            ops.add(android.content.ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(android.provider.ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withSelection(where,nameParams)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
                    .build());
        }

        if(!number.equals(""))
        {

            ops.add(android.content.ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(android.provider.ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withSelection(where,numberParams)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, number)
                    .build());
        }
        contentResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Sadly this code isn't making any changes to the contact and it's hard for me to find out why.

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

well, nobody helps me but i managed it by my own.

for anyone who gets the same issues i'm posting the answer for my own question.

the following code will update the phone, name and email's contact.

```
    public static void updateContact(Context ctx, String name, String number, String email, Long id) {
    try {
        ContentValues contentValues;

        long ret = id;
        Log.i("contact id", ret + "");

        if (!name.equals("")) {
            contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, ret);
            contentValues.put(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
            contentValues.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, name);
            ctx.getContentResolver().insert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
        }
        if (!number.equals("")) {
            contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, ret);
            contentValues.put(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
            contentValues.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, number);
            int phoneContactType = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME;
            contentValues.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, phoneContactType);
            ctx.getContentResolver().insert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
        }
        if (!email.equals("")) {
            contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, ret);
            contentValues.put(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
            contentValues.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS, email);
            contentValues.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_CUSTOM);
            ctx.getContentResolver().insert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```